# use database field to dynamically alter URL string in Phoenix App

Tags: image, elixir, phoenix-framework

So I'm trying to dynamically create the public URL for images hosted on Google Cloud storage.  Is it possible that I can call the value of the file name and append it to the structured URL, such as?

```
<%= img_tag(https://storage.googleapis.com/cods-images/uploads/<% @latestpost.thumbImg %>) %>
```

Where `@latestpost.thumbImg` matches exactly the file name?

When trying this, I get the following error:

```
keyword argument must be followed by space after: https:
```

If I do this `<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cods-images/uploads/@latestpost.thumbImg)" />` the URL just renders the value of `@latestpost.thumbImg` opposed to appending it to create the full URL string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cods-images/uploads/<%= @latestpost.thumbImg %>" />
```

Comment: That just inserts the text value from the db.

Comment: you mentioned that ```@latestpost.thumbImg``` matches exactly the filename. maybe I do not understand you correct. you do have the filename, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, but it's not constructing the full URL. So I want: `https://storage.googleapis.com/cods-images/uploads/thumbimg.jpg` therefore rendering the image, but all I see in the UI is just the text `thumbimg.jpg`

Comment: ok - what is an example content of ```latest post.thumbImg``` and what is the output of the code above?

Comment: example content of `latestpost.thumbImg` is `baThumb.jpg`, and that's the exact output

Comment: the above code renders the following output if ```latestpost.thumbImg``` is ```myImage.jpg``` -> ```<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cods-images/uploads/myImage.jpg" />```

Comment: If I look at the source code of the browser, I can actually only see myImage.jpg so it doesn't look like it's rendering the img tag at all.

Comment: Just fixed it.  Was looking at the wrong model. Sorry!